# Method being called out of order in Angular2. How to subscribe correctly?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Typescript in Angular2. I have subscribed to the response from an http request with the code below:

```
search(searchTerm): void {
   this._webservice.getSearchResult(searchTerm).subscribe(results => this.results = results);
   this.callThisMethod();
}
```

What I want to happen is to update the value of this.results and then call `this.callThisMethod()` after the variable has updated. `this.callThisMethod()` is being called out of order. How do I make the method run after variable has been updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription of the `Observable` will be called asynchronously once the response is available, not synchronously. If you want `this.callThisMethod()` to be called only then, you need to do it as part of the asynchronous callback:

```
search(searchTerm): void {
   this._webservice.getSearchResult(searchTerm)
       .subscribe(results => { 
           this.results = results;
           this.callThisMethod();
       });
}
```